# Is there a way to set keyframe progress back to 0 in Spark Studio

Tags: augmented-reality

I am trying to accomplish something, whenever I tap the screen the Object should play the keyframe animation but it only does it once. Once I tap the screen the Keyframe animation plays but when I click on the screen again nothing happens since the progress is 1 (Aka Complete) how do I reset the progress of the KeyFrame animation in the patch editor. I have attached a picture of my patch editor to better clarify.

[image]